# How to close all chrome tabs from same site (eg. google.com)

Tags: google-chrome

[image: Tabs in chrome]

When googling a lot, I usually end up with around half of the chrome tabs being just google searches (after searching I usually open the search result in a new window while looking at the results)

Is there a way to close all tabs with google searches in a single action, and not closing all non-google-tabs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may close all Google search tabs at once by using in Chrome this extension:

[Close Search Tabs](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/close-search-tabs/ecaalgnjbpjhbjlhbaiodjkmkbjfjfpb?hl=en)

It works by looking at the URL and checking for a prefix
(for example `google.con/search?q`).